# How to create a website background full of moving 'nodes' that responds to mouse movements?

Tags: html, css, animation, graphics, onmouseover

I need to change the background of my company's website to a graphic composed of moving 'nodes' (think tech-y networks) that also respond to mouse movements. For example, the image attached has the 'nodes' we are thinking of, but what we want to do wouldn't work with a simple image/video. It needs to be some sort of HTML and CSS code I am guessing, so that it responds to the mouse being in the vicinity and so that the 'nodes' will spread out around the mouse. I have no clue where to even start with this. This seems like more graphic design that I even know how to code, but if anyone has any ideas, links, etc. please let me know! Thank you. [This is the link to the example of the node network thing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9YNb.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this: https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Alternatively, there are some other options:
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17320-background-parallax-effect-on-mouse-move/

Cool stuff!  Have fun!